# EC2 instance not showing stopped when shutdown with command sudo shutdown

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-14.04

I have an EC2 instance which is getting shutdown through some bash script with command `sudo shutdown now`. The instance is getting shutdown but the AWS console still showing the instance running.
Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: You need to use AWS command line for shutdown properly. For example: `ec2-stop-instances instance_id`

Comment: @AvihooMamka Do I need to run this `aws-cli` command from the same instance from which I am running `sudo shutdown`?

Comment: You can, but not have to. You can use it from any client you want as long as you provide the correct credentials for the aws account.

Comment: @AvihooMamka Cool , I will give it a try and than will update here.

Comment: @AvihooMamka you **do not** "need" to stop an instance that way.  Instances can initiate their own shutdown, e.g. `sudo halt`, and the EC2 infrastructure *will* [stop -- or, optionally, terminate](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/terminating-instances.html#Using_ChangingInstanceInitiatedShutdownBehavior) the instance when that happens, no different than using the console, API, cli, etc.  Your advice implies otherwise, and is incorrect.  The question here should be why the normal, expected, documented behavior isn't working.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot You mean to say running `sudo halt` will show the instances in `stopped` state in aws-console?

Comment: Yes, it will.  Or, terminated, if you have configured it that way -- see the link to docs in previous comment.  The kernel sends the poweroff request to the "hardware" (which is virtual... so, to the hypervisor) which tells the infrastructure the machine has stopped and the console reflects this.

Comment: @drishtiahuja did you get a solution to this?